# wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) Hartl chapter 10...bundle exec rake db:populate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm new on rails an doing the Hartl Tutotial right now. I ran into an error while populating the DB with

```
bundle exec rake db:populate
```

This is my sample_date.rake

```
namespace :db do
desc "Fill database with sample data"
task populate: :environment do
admin = User.create!(name: "Example User",
                     email: "example@railstutorial.org",
                     password: "foobar",
                     password_confirmation: "foobar",
                     admin: true)

99.times do |n|
  name  = Faker::Name.name
  email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
  password  = "password"
  User.create!(name: name,
               email: email,
               password: password,
               password_confirmation: password)
end
users = User.all(limit: 6)
50.times do
  content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
  users.each { |user| user.microposts.create!(content: content) }
end
end
end
```

The error refers to line 24 to the argument "Users.all" but what the hack is the problem here???? I checked all my rb-files but they match with tutorial the tags.

```
$ bundle exec rake db:populate --trace
** Invoke db:populate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:populate
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib /active_record/scoping/named.rb:24:in `all'
C:/Users/Christian/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/Tutorial3/lib/tasks/sample_data.rake:19:in `block (2 levels) in
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_cha
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in to
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_han
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:populate
```

This is my Gem-File:

source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem "bootstrap-sass", '~> 3.1.1.1'
gem 'sprockets', '~> 2.11.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.5'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.14.2'
end
group :assets do 
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '2.2.1'
end
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

For any help very greatful...I got stuck here!

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, but it's worth noting in this context that the error here isn't in the tutorial. According to your Gemfile, you're using Rails 4.1, whereas the book uses Rails 4.0, and explicitly says "Unless otherwise noted, you should use the exact versions of all software used in the tutorial, including Rails itself, if you want the same results." I'm currently working on a 3rd edition that does use Rails 4.1, but for now the tutorial only works with Rails 4.0.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use

```
users = User.all.limit(6)
```

or just

```
users = User.limit(6)
```

The 'all' method doesn't take parameters.
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods/all

Comment: Iceman...thank you so much, your solution works perfectly! You actually saved me from a nervous brakedown ;-)

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow too..I just clicked the hook to green now, hope this is what you ment with "mark as solved".